# Как одну строку вывести в 2-е переменные

Tags: c++, строки

Здравствуйте допустим у меня есть строка на 1000 символов. Мне нужно разделить её на 1-е 500 и 2-е 500. 1-е 500 поместить в переменную `one` а 2-е 500 в `two` Как будет правильно это сделать?

Comment: Прикрепите Ваш код к вопросу. Без него, конечно, суть ясна, но чтобы помочь в Вашей конкретной ситуации, нужно увидеть Ваш уже имеющийся код.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string s = "Too long string ........ "; // Все 1000 символов

string one = s.substr(0,500);
string two = s.substr(500,500);
```

или вторую строку просто до конца -

```
string two = s.substr(500);
```